# How to implement reliable/repeatable Android Nearby Connections

Tags: android, google-nearby-connections

Im investigating Android Nearby connections API and having difficulty when attempting to reconnect p2p_cluster.

the first time i install my application on my test devices I can establish a working "mesh" and communications work as expected between host and clients.

however when i stop advertising and discovering on all the devices and attempt to re-establish connections my devices are "stuck" advertising/discovering and i cannot make any connections.

i have followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) and cannot see where i have made any mistakes.

even when i try the google samples such as the walkieTalkie app, i experience the same issue. the initial connection is made fine and works as expected, however all subsequent attempts to re establish connections fail.

where am i going wrong?
why doesnt the official documented google code work in a repeatable manner?
is there a "secret" to properly reseting the nearby connection on a device in order to have it reconnect without having to force close the application and restart the app "from scratch"?